# Failed to load resource: 404 (Not Found) - Data are not passed to the backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I get 404 error when i read and send those data to the back-end.

[image]

i Have a MEAN web app ..below i have added wriiten codes

Controller

```
$scope.addFileContents= function(readDetails)
{
var lines = readDetails.split('\n');
for(var line = 0; line < lines.length-1; line++){
var logFileContent = ""; 
var linesSpace = lines[line].split(' ');
for(var y=3;y <= linesSpace.length-1;y++){
logFileContent +=linesSpace[y];
logFileContent += " ";
  }   
var event = {
dat: linesSpace[0],
tim: linesSpace[1],
details: logFileContent,  
 };
 Event.ReadUploadFile(event)
  .success(function () {
      $scope.status = 'Reading the selected file';          
  })
  .error(function (error) {
      $scope.status = 'Unable to insert data: ' ;
  });
```

}
}

Service

```
  ReadUploadFile : function(event) {
        return $http.post('/api/filesReadUpload', event);
        $window.location.reload();
    },
```

Route

```
app.post('/api/filesReadUpload', function(req, res) {

    var events=new filesReadUpload({

        dat:req.body.dat,
        details:req.body.details,
        tim:req.body.tim,
             });

    events.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
        return res.send(err);

        res.json({    message: 'Read file!'  });
              });
        });
```

model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema  = mongoose.Schema;
var filesUpload= new Schema({

_id:String,
dat:String,
details:String,
tim:String,

},
{
versionKey: false
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('filesReadUpload',filesUpload);
```

can anyone  suggest a way to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: It seems like the `/api/filesReadUpload` ends with a 404 error. Make sure to restart the server process when editing the server files (e.g. maybe you added the new route, but forgot to restart the server, which means you will have a 404).

Comment: I see `if (err)
        return res.send(err);` this maybe return error code 404,  you can show me what is `filesReadUpload` or check it again

Comment: actually the fault was found.it was a mistake that i have done in the model.Thank you very much for your responses.